# How to remove from second occurrence until the end of the file?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

How to remove from a second occurrence of a pattern and delete only all the remaining occurrences in a file?

**What I have done:**

```
awk '/Type ;Rho ;DelSqRho ;Bond Ellipticity ;V ;G ;K ;L ;/{p++}p==1' file
Pattern: "Type ;Rho ;DelSqRho ;Bond Ellipticity ;V ;G ;K ;L ;"
```

**Input**

```
Type ;Rho ;Rho at Nucleus ;DelSqRho ;Bond Ellipticity ;V ;G ;K; L;
 (3,-3) NACP C2;  1.1958513197E+02;  1.1958513183E+02; -5.4465523878E+05; NA; -1.3618005730E+05;  8.1237999095E+00;  1.3617193350E+05;
Type ;Rho ;Rho at Nucleus ;DelSqRho ;Bond Ellipticity ;V ;G ;K; L;
 (3,-3) NACP C3;  1.1958827553E+02;  1.1958827351E+02; -5.4468085564E+05; NA; -1.3618586067E+05;  7.8233806895E+00;  1.3617803729E+05;
Type ;Rho ;Rho at Nucleus ;DelSqRho ;Bond Ellipticity ;V ;G ;K; L;
 (3,-3) NACP C4;  1.1959808288E+02;  1.1959808234E+02; -5.4473956436E+05; NA; -1.3620048021E+05;  7.7945613266E+00;  1.3619268565E+05;
```

**Expected output**

```
Type ;Rho ;Rho at Nucleus ;DelSqRho ;Bond Ellipticity ;V ;G ;K; L;
 (3,-3) NACP C2;  1.1958513197E+02;  1.1958513183E+02; -5.4465523878E+05; NA; -1.3618005730E+05;  8.1237999095E+00;  1.3617193350E+05;
 (3,-3) NACP C3;  1.1958827553E+02;  1.1958827351E+02; -5.4468085564E+05; NA; -1.3618586067E+05;  7.8233806895E+00;  1.3617803729E+05;
 (3,-3) NACP C4;  1.1959808288E+02;  1.1959808234E+02; -5.4473956436E+05; NA; -1.3620048021E+05;  7.7945613266E+00;  1.3619268565E+05;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk '/^Type/{if(p++)next} 1' file
Type ;Rho ;Rho at Nucleus ;DelSqRho ;Bond Ellipticity ;V ;G ;K; L;
 (3,-3) NACP C2;  1.1958513197E+02;  1.1958513183E+02; -5.4465523878E+05; NA; -1.3618005730E+05;  8.1237999095E+00;  1.3617193350E+05;
 (3,-3) NACP C3;  1.1958827553E+02;  1.1958827351E+02; -5.4468085564E+05; NA; -1.3618586067E+05;  7.8233806895E+00;  1.3617803729E+05;
 (3,-3) NACP C4;  1.1959808288E+02;  1.1959808234E+02; -5.4473956436E+05; NA; -1.3620048021E+05;  7.7945613266E+00;  1.3619268565E+05;
```

Answer (score 4):

The same thing with `sed`:

```
sed '0,/^Type /b; /^Type /d' file
```

Output:

```
Type ;1Rho ;Rho at Nucleus ;DelSqRho ;Bond Ellipticity ;V ;G ;K; L;
 (3,-3) NACP C2;  1.1958513197E+02;  1.1958513183E+02; -5.4465523878E+05; NA; -1.3618005730E+05;  8.1237999095E+00;  1.3617193350E+05;
 (3,-3) NACP C3;  1.1958827553E+02;  1.1958827351E+02; -5.4468085564E+05; NA; -1.3618586067E+05;  7.8233806895E+00;  1.3617803729E+05;
 (3,-3) NACP C4;  1.1959808288E+02;  1.1959808234E+02; -5.4473956436E+05; NA; -1.3620048021E+05;  7.7945613266E+00;  1.3619268565E+05;
```

**Explanation:**

- `/^Type /d` - delete lines starting with `Type`
- `0,/^Type /b` - from the beginning of file to the first line matching `Type`, branch to the end of script -- that is, skip over the deletion command
- the above rule uses 0 as a first address instead of 1, since otherwise `/^Type /` is only tested starting with line 2, thus keeping two `Type ...` lines.

Comment: Would you explain it?

Comment: very good use of GNU sed. For posix version, some modification (`0` is not allowed ) but same concept could be use.

Comment: and less syntax compared to awk.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) command:

```
awk '$0 !~ /Type ;Rho.* ;DelSqRho ;Bond Ellipticity ;V ;G ;K; L;/ || FNR < 2' infile
```

It does two conditions, `FNR < 2` prints first line, the header. And the other one every line that does not match the header again.

It yields:

```
Type ;Rho ;Rho at Nucleus ;DelSqRho ;Bond Ellipticity ;V ;G ;K; L;
 (3,-3) NACP C2;  1.1958513197E+02;  1.1958513183E+02; -5.4465523878E+05; NA; -1.3618005730E+05;  8.1237999095E+00;  1.3617193350E+05;
 (3,-3) NACP C3;  1.1958827553E+02;  1.1958827351E+02; -5.4468085564E+05; NA; -1.3618586067E+05;  7.8233806895E+00;  1.3617803729E+05;
 (3,-3) NACP C4;  1.1959808288E+02;  1.1959808234E+02; -5.4473956436E+05; NA; -1.3620048021E+05;  7.7945613266E+00;  1.3619268565E+05;
```